# reading image into R

Tags: image, r, tiff, pixel

I am interested in seeing if it is possible to read information about pixels from an imported TIFF image, then create an excel file containing the xy location and RGB color code for each pixel in the image.

Comment: See the package list on CRAN, there are packages rtiff and tiff, also rgdal (which is more specialist).  With rgdal you can do library(rgdal);as.data.frame(readGDAL("file.tif")) and that's basically it. *Why* on earth you would want a TIFF file in Excel is another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as.raster` to convert your image to a raster. An object of class "raster" is a matrix of colour values as given by rgb representing a bitmap image.

Here an axample using `png` as source:

```
library(png)
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
## convert it to a raster, interpolate =F to select only sample of pixels of img
img.r <- as.raster(img,interpolate=F)
 str(img.r)
 'raster' chr [1:76, 1:100] "#00000000" "#00000000" "#00000000" "#00000000" "#00000000" "#00000000" "#00000000"
```

To save it , use something like:

```
write.csv(img.r,'image.csv')
```